# How to adjust link to correct line in an R code

Tags: r

I would like to add one more column named `icon` in my dataframe. For the first line, I would like to insert the following link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png

And for the second line the following link: https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25694.png

```
df<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.87, -23.8), Longitude = c(-49.6666666666667, 
-49.6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I did like this:

```
df$Icon<-"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png"
```

However, the second line has the incorrect link, how to adjust?

Comment: `df$Icon <- c("https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png", "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25694.png")`

Comment: your `df$Icon <- 'https://developers...beachflag` would be written to all rows, where `df$Icon[1] <-` to the first row, and `<- c('link1', 'link2'` allocates to rows as desired, in the order they are in your `c(`.